# Can't call PHP contents from another file

Tags: php, joomla

i'm developing a Joomla module, and i'm testing the basic approach. I have my first file:

FILE1.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');
$AdVisualV2jMODPHP_ver='0.3.0070';
$Station_ID = $params->get('Station_ID');

$Start=0;
$Page=10;
echo 'AVVIAMO LA PROCEDURA 0.0.66 - '.$Station_ID.'<br>';
echo '<div id="TabellaEventi"></div>';
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Avanti" ONCLICK="avanti()"> ';
echo '<INPUT Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Indietro" ONCLICK="indietro()"> ';
echo '<br>';
?>

<script>

function avanti() {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            Esito=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','DisplayEvents.php',false);
    xmlhttp.send();
//  document.write(Esito);
    document.getElementById('TabellaEventi').innerHTML='CLICCO QUESTO AVANTI';
}

function indietro() {
    document.getElementById('TabellaEventi').innerHTML='Pulsante INDIETRO nella div<br>questo su due righe<br>';
}
</script>
```

Here there is the file DisplayEvents.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Da qui siamo nella routine display<br>';
echo 'Procediamo pure<br>';
?>
```

I've used other times this way, with XMLHttpRequest i put all the text output of the file DisplayEvents.php and I put it in the variable Evento, then I can print or do what I want. But simply does not work.

I've used this way other times in an HTML file with a PHP, this time is PHP with PHP, but i can't understand.

Where I'm wrong this time? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information you provided, I am curious to see if it is an issue with your path's.

Change:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','DisplayEvents.php',false);
```

To:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET','/DisplayEvents.php',false);
```

Use Chrome's Developer Console or Firefox and FireBug and look at the response on the network tabs. This will show you the status and response codes clearly.

Also, take a look at your `access_logs` and see if there are entries for the calls to the `DisplayEvents.php` file.

Comment: NO THE PATH WAS BAD! I had controlled, but NOT in the way you suggested, thank you very much